# Creating Action Bar Tabs from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to create ActionBar Tabs from a Fragment?

I am using ABS Library and have 2 Fragments. The data in the second Fragment is changing dynamically and Is it possible to show tabs from a Fragment dynamically?

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);        
         getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
                tab.setText("Tab " + i);
                tab.setTabListener(this);
                getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
            }
    }
```

This is the code I have and I am getting `The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

never mind,

just used getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar()

Worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast to your activity (say `ActivityExtendsActionBarActivity`) which extends `ActionBarActivity`:

```
((ActivityExtendsActionBarActivity)getSupportActionBar()).setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```